# How can I add multiple docs with 1 write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder if somebody would know how I can add multiple docs to my collection in the firestore with only using 1 write. Because I have more than 20.000 records but I don't want to pay for firestore. Is there a possibility to add multiple docs in 1 write ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.  Each document written costs 1 write.  They can't be bundled together in an operation that is only billed a single write.

Comment: In fact, that's why the pricing unit is called a **document write**. To reduce the charges, you can consider merging multiple pieces of content into a single document though.